# Are compiler optimization questions appropriate for SO?

Tags: discussion

I saw this question ["In C++, should I bother to cache variables, or let the compiler do the optimization?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33898371/in-c-should-i-bother-to-cache-variables-or-let-the-compiler-do-the-optimizat).

And the answers are going to be not only compiler-specific, but also compiler-version and optimization level. They are also very local since you can imagine asking the same question for hundreds of different scenarios.

The answers are also going to be outdated in the near future, and seem much like the "list of books" questions that were deemed not appropriate on SO ages ago.

So, are questions like the linked one appropriate for SO?

Comment: That example question alone seems to make it a resounding "heck yes" :) Seeing how much activity there has been in that one question alone, apparently it is a hot topic much appreciated. But you also see the other side of the fence happening: immediate rejection by making a reference to premature optimization the "answer".

Comment: @Gimby the book list questions also had lots of activity, so activity is an insufficient condition. The question as asked leads to answers of "depending on your compiler" which is objective, but unless someone makes an answer with every compiler, there is no right answer.

Comment: Not really a fair comparison IMO; the book question went all places. This is strictly grounded in the area of programming and programming tools. I do want to rephrase: Activity = adding knowledge and test results. Its a proper beehive.

Comment: @Gimby "beehive"?

Comment: The question flags up a specific case where the language definitiion means a seemingly simple optimization cannot be done by any compiler. I'd initially classed it as another premature optimization question, but - accidentally - it's a lot deeper than that.

Comment: @Roddy when the question is "does the language allow for this?" then the question's answer will be objective and final (find the standard), but when it's about optimization then it depends on many variables. IMHO the question's intent is unsuitable, but in the answering it has uncovered something useful.

Comment: @ArtB https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beehive . You know, those things where bees are constantly busy busy busy working together to improve and expand. In most questions you're lucky if you get one or two short answers.

Comment: How is this even a question? It's one of the few areas where we still go in depth here on SO besides useless language lawyer questions whether an obscure unreadable piece of code is valid.

Answer (score 33):

#### Yes, I think they should be.

I understand where you are trying to get to with the questions' being local, but this applies to a lot of cases here on SO. What I see is this question has been searched for a lot, so its content is rather useful and similar questions should be allowed as on-topic in the future.

Answer (score 14):

**That Question is Awesome!**

That question is actually really great even though it might look really horrible and smelly. Please keep it open.

It leads to something optimizers *typically* don't do the best job of optimizing, and that's when aliasing is involved. There are interesting presentations from game developers on this subject from the likes of Christer Ericson (God of War fame) which are old but not necessarily outdated.

Mysticial actually provided one of the simplest, most practical, general kind of theoretical answers from the compiler design perspective on why this case is difficult to optimize (unless inlined to a point where sufficient info is available) in the comments:

> If I was a compiler, I would see that your two examples aren't the
>   same. It's possible that p points to the same memory as bitmap->width.
>   Therefore I can't legally optimize the first example to the second
>   one.

... which is something I always find annoying, when really great answers are in the comment section (sometimes making me wish an up-vote of a comment at least awarded something).

But this is one of those questions that might have stumbled upon a very reasonable Q&A topic, even if by total accident. It's a question that now belongs in my personal favorites/bookmark, since it's a really useful thing for a developer like me to keep in mind.

Actually a lot of my posts on meta relate to this topic of a seemingly-bad question. Some of the most fruitful Q&As on the site will be in a grey zone where they *look* like really bad questions (and might even be in terms of the site's rules). But they actually aren't in terms of providing information that is very interesting to others and answers which point out something very interesting and unexpected.

Comment: "That question is actually really great even though it looks really horrible and smelly" - I don't know whether I should take it as a compliment ;)

Comment: @YaronCohen-Tal Apologies, no offense intended! Though I was wondering, would you mind if I make a modest edit? I think so many of those complaining about premature optimization would hush a bit if we changed just one line in your post. Instead of *"Is it worth optimizing it by writing"*, something like, *"Could there be a case where this could yield more efficient results by writing"* or something along those lines.

Comment: That kind of edit should move it to a more conceptual realm so that people feel less inclined to suggest other things like profiling and not worrying about this.

Comment: Sure, I agree. I see that you've edited the question, thanx.

Comment: Unfortunately, the edit totally changed the question. The new question *"could this be more efficient"* gets an undisputed YES, while the old *"is it worth optimizing..."* gets - in my mind - a pretty solid "it depends, but almost certainly NO". My answer (to the original question!) now stands with 6 upvotes but 7 downvotes!

Comment: Ugh I see -- though did all 7 downvotes come within the past hour (pretty fresh edit)? But I do see how there's a conflict of interest here between preserving the original wording vs site posterity.

Comment: @Ike no, they'd been creeping up slowly, but a couple more in the last hour :) The revised question (and its answers) is an excellent one though.

Comment: Apologies about that if it might have lead to some more downvotes!

Comment: @Ike: Actually, your answer is pretty good, but the question itself is not awesome (no apparent research, ...). Of course, it might just be that the OP does not have much prior knowledge: after all, we all started somewhere.

Comment: @MatthieuM. That's kind of a point I've been trying to make in various posts. I don't judge a "great question" so much on its own, but more on the probability that it can yield very fruitful, educational answers. In my opinion what's encouraged as a great question doesn't always align with that fact -- the most meticulously constructed troubleshooting question with an MCVE doesn't necessary provide answers with the level of posterity that even this very general question can provide. Those often benefit few other than the original author of the question.

Comment: @MatthieuM. So my ideas of what makes a "great question" is solely based on the kind of answers it would receive. I commented about this question early on when it only had a few votes, and now look how much attention it has received. Yet it also has 3 close votes. To me that suggests that there's something a bit wrong with the way we judge a "good question" vs. a "bad question".

Comment: @MatthieuM. Though to be fair, maybe part of the reason it got all these up-votes and activity is solely because of the spotlight we put on it here at meta. I might just be commenting on a self-fulfilled prophecy -- but it seemed very much to me, even from the start, that this question was going to be a great... because it's exactly the kind of general question that tends to produce some amazing answers... Noticed I said "going to be", because I'm judging the quality of a question based on the answers that are likely to come up.

Answer (score 7):

"Do compilers perform the foo-frob optimization?"  Well, try a few and see for yourself, or at least read the compilers' documentation (such as the list of optimization flags).  Besides, you probably want more than a "yes, here's an example" or "no" answer.  If you're willing to do some work before asking, you can ask a question that will probably teach you more.

If you don't know how to verify the optimization is being performed, "How can I verify that the foo-frob optimization is being performed on this minimal code example?" is a reasonable question.  You'll probably learn something about reading assembly/bytecode/IR, and maybe also learn *why* the foo-frob optimization improves performance (or doesn't!) from the standpoint of the machine, instead of in terms of the source language.

If you've tried a few compilers and the results aren't what you expect, then you can ask more useful questions like:

"Is the foo-frob optimization legal?"  An objectively answerable language-lawyer question that often yields insights about the language semantics beyond just the foo-frob optimization.

"Compiler X claims to implement the foo-frob optimization, but it doesn't perform it on this reduced example of my code.  How can I massage my code to convince the compiler to perform the optimization?"  Also objectively answerable, and gets to the pragmatics of what analysis the compiler has to do to prove the foo-frob optimization (and probably other optimizations) is safe.  You might consider searching compiler X's bug tracker before posting, to ensure it isn't a known problem.

Comment: I agree with you, understanding how compilers work, and what they can (and cannot) optimize can be very useful when attempting to write performance critical code. It certainly seems more efficient to apply "guided" changes than randomly tweaking the code in the hope of getting further performance. On the other hand, most "optimization" related questions are usually rather vague, and the answers have to go well beyond the question to provide interesting information.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Indeed, these types of questions will likely start out incomplete and with wrong testing metrics and thus will require effort to be in any kind of useful and answerable shape. Not really a problem in itself I'd say, but probably it will create some headaches in both duplicate matching and review queues.

Comment: A test cannot tell you under what specific circumstances the optimization is applied. For that reason "Just test it" is not a good reply. The question is kind of bad because it should be "Under what circumstances does this work?". He did not ask that but it's easy to interpret it that way and salvage it.